# Combine regular expressions without padding the results in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not sure about the terminology, but let me try and explain what I want to achieve. I have a lot of HTML code, wherein I need ro replace parts of name- and id-attributes (amongst others).

These attributes may contain strings such as `VALUE[1][0][question][0]`, `VALUE[1][0][answer][0]` but also `MEDIA_1` and `openMedia(1, '', 'title')`.

In those strings I sometimes need to replace the second and last `[0]` with `[1]` or `MEDIA_1` with `MEDIA_2` or `openMedia(1, '', 'title')` with `openMedia(2, '', 'title')` and so on.

To keep things simple (or not), I've come up with the following regex:

```
/(VALUE)\[(\d+)\]\[(\d+)\]\[(.*?)\]\[(\d+)\]|(MEDIA)_(\d+)|(openMedia)\((\d+),/gm
```

I'm trying to capture individual prefixes such as `openMedia` to be able to loop through the results and do the replacements according to said prefix. I hope I'm being clear enough. I use the following code to loop through the results:

```
while ((m = regex.exec(html)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
     regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  console.log(m);
}
```

My problem is that m sometimes looks like this:

```
Array [ "VALUE[1][0][question][0]", "VALUE", "1", "0", "question", "0", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]
Array [ "openMedia(1,", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "openMedia", "1" ]
```

How do I get an "unpadded" result? I expect the Array to simply be

```
Array [ "openMedia(1,", "openMedia", "1" ]
```

for instance.

Comment: Your question seems to be more that you want `undefined` values removed from an array: `arr.filter(x => x !== undefined)`

Comment: optionals return undefined when not matched. You can just filter out the undefined results `str.match(re).filter( x => x)`

Comment: @trincot beat me by 30 seconds... laughing that we both used x. :)

Comment: :-) Just be careful that your version would also kick `''` out of the result.

Comment: The `undefined` values are invaluable when you need to know if a group matched or not, that is why the number of items in the array will always be the number of capturing groups + 1 (for the whole match). To remove them, you have to use some `filter`  as a post-process step.

Comment: @trincot didn't even think of that, totally a valid way of doing it and probably what I am going to do in fact, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew I see, that makes sense. Thanks for sharing! :)

Comment: @ynamite, as it seems useful, I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to be more that you want `undefined` values removed from an array. This you can do with `filter`:

```
m = m.filter(x => x !== undefined)
```

This will reduce this:

```
[ "openMedia(1,", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "openMedia", "1" ]
```

To:

```
[ "openMedia(1,", "openMedia", "1" ]
```

Comment: Also didn't know about the filter function, thanks again, great answer to a sub par question ;)